# merging two different string lists to a class list

Tags: c#, list, linq, class

I have a class as such:

```
class Item
{
    public string eventName{ get; set; }
    public string performanceTime { get; set; }
}
```

and I have two lists of data:

```
List<string> progName = getProgrammingNames();
List<string> progTimes = getProgrammingTimes()
```

Inside both string lists are data and I would like to merge them to

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the items together and then project the `Item` class:

```
var result = progName.Zip(progTimes, (name, time) => new Item { 
    eventName = name, 
    performanceTime = time }).ToList();
```

As `Zip` only returns items with same index if one collection is bigger than other it will be missing those items. In that case you can use a form of full outer join:

```
var result = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(progName.Count, progTimes.Count))
             join n in progName.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }) on i equals n.index into names
             from n in names.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join t in progTimes.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }) on i equals t.index into times
             from t in times.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new Item { eventName = n?.item, performanceTime = t?.item };
```

Comment: if an event name has many performance times, is there anyway to repeat the same event name for a given time

Comment: @shikiko - what do you mean? You have two separate collections. How do you tell which item in the first belongs to one in the second?

Comment: like for example if event A has multiple performance times 
eg. 
Event | Performance Time
Event A | 10:50,11:30
Event B | 9:00, 10:00

how do i add them accordingly

Comment: Yes but you have one list containing only the names, and a second containing only time. How do you then tell which name is for which time? what do the `getProgrammingNames` and `getProgrammingTimes` do?

Comment: I have a separate `list<int> weeks` that contains elements like {5,3}. So basically, the 5 refers to the times that goes to the first event

Comment: @shikiko - That is a very different question and I don't really understand the logic of the merging. I suggest try first and then post another question with the description of the 3 lists, some sample data for each and expected result. Also please post it in a way that it compiles - so it is easier to help. If you wish you can comment me and I will be happy to try and help

Answer (score 1):

A simple For loop is not enough?

```
        List<string> progName = getProgrammingNames();
        List<string> progTimes = getProgrammingTimes();

        if (progName.Count != progTimes.Count)
            throw new Exception("2 list counts are different");

        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

        for (var l_i = 0; l_i < progName.Count; l_i++)
        {
            itemList.Add(new Item()
            {
                eventName = progName[l_i],
                performanceTime = progTimes[l_i]
            });
        }
```